# How to remove null characters at the end of a user input string?

Tags: c++, string, cin, null-character

I have an array of 20 strings with a maximum of 81 characters that will be populated by the user, how do I go about removing the excess null characters at the end should the users input be > 81 characters?

I've tried to search for solutions to this, but most seem to require me to know how many characters the user has input into the string before the program is run.

```cpp
int main()
{
    string strings[20];

    cout << "Enter up to 20 strings, press enter when done: ";

    input(strings);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (strings[i] == "\0")
            break;
        else
        {
            strings[i].resize(81);
            cout << "Here is string" << i << ": " << endl << strings[i] << endl;
            menu(strings[i]);
        }

    }

void input(string strings[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, strings[i]);
        if (strings[i] == "\0")
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "_how do I go about removing the excess null characters at the end should the users input_" What excess null characters? Strings that you read via `std::getline` will not contain any null characters..

Comment: You are either taking unusual input or handling the input strangely to make this a problem. Can you please expand on the problem to demonstrate how you are using the input and add a sample input set?

Comment: why do you think that you have to remove null-characters? I have the feeling this is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where X actually is no problem. What makes you think there is a problem?

Comment: `strings[i] == "\0"` is an unusual way of doing `strings[i].empty()` ([empty](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty)).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
strings[i] = strings[i].substr(0, 81)
```

I haven't worked with C++ in awhile but this should just trim the input to the first 81 characters. Better yet, apply this when you first get the input or return a user input error to the user if too long.

Comment: Thank you for the help!